# How do I install a gamepad with vibration?

Tags: gamepad

I've been looking at gamepads for my gaming needs and so far I haven't found a single opinion as to what works and what doesn't. Are there any gamepads that have the rumble (vibration) feature working? Can I use multiple PS3/X360 gamepads at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The Xbox 360 -one works fine for me, but I haven't tested vibration.

I can test vibration, if you point me to a game (in the Ubuntu archives, preferably) that uses it.

Comment: As far as I'm aware Super Meat Boy and Shank should use vibration. I'm not aware of any free games in the USC that use it though.

Comment: Sorry, I can't be of more help then.